# Xampp - acesso pelo Android

Tags: android, xampp

tenho uma WS fajunta que fiz apenas para praticar e outro dia por falta do que fazer, coloquei no navegador do meu android o ip/xampp e apareceu a mensagem de "Acesso proibido!", não sabia que era possivel fazer acesso pelo android, gostaria de saber como faço para acessa-lo e para que utilidade isto serviria (Acreditando eu, que isso serviria para poder mexer no meu Web Sevice e configurações do Xampp remoto), agradeço desde já!!

Answer (score 1):

Você está acessando uma instalação XAMPP instalada na sua rede local, não no seu celular.

Isso poderia acontecer até com um dispositivo no qual você não consegue instalar nada, como uma TV ou um celular antigo.

A mensagem **Acesso proibido** quer dizer que aquela instalação foi modificada e não funciona do jeito que você está acessando. O padrão seria /xampp exibir informações sobre o servidor. Se você não administra tal instalação, nem sabe o que está instalado ou como acessar, você pode, no máximo, advinhar o acesso: /xampp, /phpmyadmin, /login.php etc. - mas é capaz que nada esteja instalado.

A **utilidade** é que é um servidor, provavelmente de desenvolvimento. Não sei sobre sua rede, mas é capaz que esteja num lugar público e alguem nessa rede tem um servidor instalado, ou alguem está testando coisas. Para você não tem utilidade nenhuma, mas como o XAMPP provavelmente não está instalado no seu celular, não prejudica você também.

Comment: Entendi, mas repetindo: Como faço para acessa-lo (Como disse, está dando acesso proibido) e qual a utilidade??

Comment: Acrescentei minha resposta. Ajudou?

Comment: Agora deu pra entender melhor, como antes não sabia sobre isso, agora pelo menos tenho uma base. Agradeço!!

Comment: Imagina, e bem-vindo no stackoverflow.com!

Answer (score 0):

Verifique no **httpd.conf** se dentro dele há uma configuração **Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8** mude ela para **Allow from All** e reinicie o seu servidor httpd.

> Segue abaixo link de pergunta quase igual a sua (semelhante a sua em inglês)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, por falta de tempo, não pude fazer o teste, mas em breve testarei!!